# Array of std::vector's doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'd like to manage three std::vectors and thought about a solution like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> nums[3];
  nums[0].push_back(1);
  nums[0].push_back(3);
  nums[0].push_back(5);
  nums[1].push_back(10);
  nums[1].push_back(20);
  nums[1].push_back(30);
  nums[2].push_back(100);
  nums[2].push_back(300);
  nums[2].push_back(500);
  nums[2].push_back(700);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < nums[0].size(); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", nums[0].at(i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nums[1].size(); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", nums[2].at(i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < nums[2].size(); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", nums[2].at(i));
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I don't understand the compiler output. Any idea how I can fix this?

**gcc:**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "std::__1::__vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const",
>   referenced from:
>         void std::__1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(int const&) in code-4a0a01.o   "std::__1::__vector_base_common::__throw_out_of_range() const",
>   referenced from:
>         std::__1::vector >::at(unsigned long) in code-4a0a01.o   "std::terminate()", referenced from:
>         ___clang_call_terminate in code-4a0a01.o   "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
>         std::__1::__vector_base >::~__vector_base() in code-4a0a01.o
>         std::__1::__split_buffer&>::~__split_buffer() in code-4a0a01.o
>   "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         std::__1::__split_buffer&>::__split_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned
>   long, std::__1::allocator&) in code-4a0a01.o
>   "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
>         ___clang_call_terminate in code-4a0a01.o   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
>         _main in code-4a0a01.o
>         void std::__1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(int const&) in code-4a0a01.o
>         Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in code-4a0a01.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What command are you using to compile your code?

Comment: Use `g++` to compile c++ code.

Comment: @Olaf May be point out the specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `gcc` which is C compiler. C programming language does not support STL (Standard Template Library). Use `g++`, which is C++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry for my inattention!

Comment: Technically, `g++` is just an alias for `gcc`. `g++` includes some various flags to use the C++ libraries and headers, but it is still only `gcc`.